# How can I make spring MVC PathVariable more robust?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-rest, path-variables

In `PathVariable` example below:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
SomeReturn get(@PathVariable Long id)
{
      ....
}
```

If I call this API like `/api/100abc`, will get a number format exception.

Is there any way to make `id` more robust, for example:

- `/api/100`
- `/api/100abc`

In both of them, I'd like to call `/api/100`.

I know I can change the API parameter type of path variable from `Long` to `String`, and do some logic to make things done.

Is there any other way like AOP or Filter to do so?

Comment: Seems like AOP is the way to go. Have you looked at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder?

Comment: @GetMapping("/{id}")
     public String get(@PathVariable("id") Object id) {
      //TODO
    }  ??

Comment: You can make it more robust by implementing custom **binding** or **formatting** you can read the docs here for: [Data Binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-initbinder) [Field Formatting](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder

You can try :

```java
public class RobustId {
    private Long id;

    public RobustId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // getters and setters below...
}

public class RobustIdConverter implements Converter<String, RobustId> {

    @Override
    public RobustId convert(String from) {
        Long id = null;

        for (int i=0; i<from.length(); i++) {
            char c = from.charAt(i);
            if ( !Character.isDigit(c) ) {
                id = Long.parseLong(from.substring(0, i));
                break;
            }
        }
        return new RobustId(id);
    }
}

@GetMapping("/{id}")
SomeReturn get(@PathVariable RobustId id) {
      ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can (make path variable "more robust")! ... by implementing custom "binding" and/or "formatting".

> Some annotated controller method arguments that represent String-based request input (such as @RequestParam, @RequestHeader, **@PathVariable**, @MatrixVariable, and @CookieValue) **can require type conversion if the argument is declared as something other than String**.
> For such cases, type conversion is automatically applied based on the configured converters. By default, simple types (int, long, Date, and others) are supported. You can customize type conversion through a WebDataBinder (see [DataBinder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-initbinder)) or by registering Formatters with the FormattingConversionService. [See Spring Field Formatting](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#format).
> ...

Source: [MVC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-typeconversion)|[WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-typeconversion)